# CSS: 100% is larger than page width?

Tags: html, css

I'm  busy with a new website. For the menu bar, I put the width on `100%` to be seen here:

```
font-family: 'Champagne';
    font-size:20px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0193CF;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 2em;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
```

But for some strange reason, the width of the menu bar is actually longer then the rest of the page. Take a look at the screenshot at the bottom.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

[image: 100% is to large...]

Comment: Padding? Have you tried removing it? Or look into `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: And also `box-sizing: border-box` if you are using borders.

Comment: "Does anyone have any experience with this?" - yeah this sort of crap happens all the time. Use your browsers developer (f12) tools and inspect the element. You can check the size of it and its parent elements and see why it's too wide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is a combination of `width` and `padding` properties. Padding, in the typical CSS box model, is *additive*. If your box `width` is 100%, the `padding` applied to it will *add* to the width. The `width` would therefore calculate at a number greater than the size set in your `width` property.

I would suggest using the `box-sizing` properties in your CSS, like so:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**width: 100% + padding: 0 2em, is equal to something greater than 100%.** By using the  `box-sizing` property in your style sheet, you will tell the browser to include padding's as part of the *total* width.

Comment: Inverting the problem is not a solution. Let's say I want an element big enough to fit a 600px image in it, but that also has a 5px border, suddenly "why is my image overflowing the container that should be the right size for it???"

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm not sure I follow what you mean. In your example, you probably wouldn't set a width at all. You would let the image stretch the box accordingly.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UEbw/embedded/result/). Notice now in the first case, the input box overflows but the image is snug, whereas in the second the problem is inverted.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Pick your poision is what i would say when it comes to that type of stuff.  It has become not just common but recommended to include the above styles on all of your sites.  It solves far more problems than it creates.  In-fact, it doesn't really create problems, you just have to adapt to the model properly.

Comment: I would argue it's more to do with you setting an exact width on the containing div that holds the image. You wouldn't need to in this instance. See this fork, http://jsfiddle.net/9MZ38/, where the box that holds the image has an auto width instead. This way it will fit any image, box-sizing or not.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo You're also using `display:inline-block`, which may not be suitable for the situation ;)

Comment: @Michael Personally I just have a `.borderbox` class or similar, which I can drop on any element that needs that particular style. Much easier.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Easier?  Not sure I agree with that.  Adding that class to a number elements is tedious at best, especially when applying to everything truly doesn't create a problem.  The image issue you posted above is easily fixed by a simple max-width: 100%; on your img, which is something that you should be doing at bare minimum for responsive images anyways.  And any other more intuitive responsive image solution will also fix the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/HvYf4/

Sorry, but border-box simply does not create any problems, that arent solved by things you should also be doing anyways.

Comment: @Michael But now the image is scaled down slightly despite there being room for it at full size in a responsive layout. The point I'm trying to make here is that a blanket solution does *not* solve the problem because it can easily (and often does) cause more problems.

Comment: Except the size of the entire block is 336px, if you want the image to be 336px and the border is 10px thick you just set the width of .w336 to 346px.  I'm tellin ya this isn't an issue, it's purely a matter of modifying your concept of the box model, something that someone as prestigious as Chris Coyier is adamant about.

Your statement, as a statement alone, is correct, blanket solutions are generally bad.  Border-box as a blanket solution is a moot point however.

Comment: Also if you want the image frame to take full width in a responsive layout, the width of .w336 class would be 100% anyways, in which case, again, there is NO problem.

Answer (score 3):

`box-sizing:border-box`...
This basically takes into consideration the margin and padding when calculating the size.

A more detailed explaination on the box-model is outlined for you here:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Another option to cover most cross-browser problems is to try using a reset to zero out all elements and bring you back to a true "start".

many browsers add their own little tidbits of padding oand spacing on specific elements, so a reset is often used to, well, reset your browser to a true "square one"

Here is one of the more popular ones:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

But this site reviews a lot of them:

http://www.css-reset.com/

Comment: Wow. I'd never heard of this, is it widely used?

Comment: Most of this answer is bunk. `box-sizing:border-box` is all that matters here.

Comment: very. but do not get caught up and make the mistake of the all encompassing `* { margin:0; padding:0; } ` as it can do more harm then good. Ultimately, you be the judge of what you need.

Comment: @niet... if box sizing tripped the op up, then a reset may also help them... as we find out the op never knew they existed so a discover has been made thanks to this "bunk" post.

Answer (score 1):

If `box-sizing` doesn't fix this problem for people, check your top levels of your CSS - I found a rogue `width:100%` for the `<body>` CSS once.

My technique for debugging these problems is to open Developer Tools and delete blocks of the page (i.e. major `<div>`s) one at a time: if removing any of them causes the layout to snap back into place that indicates the one you just deleted was causing the problem.

Comment: That's a helpful debugging tip.

Answer (score 0):

`width` sets the content width which does not include padding nor margins.

Try removing padding or changing the box sizing.